# Having problems solving Leetcode Question Max Area of Islands

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Below is my code to find the max area of islands but for some reason it kept failing this test case:
[[1],[1]]

Im not entirely sure whats wrong and Ive been thinking to no avail of a possible solution using this method. It was thinking a possible reason why this code is not working properly is because of the synchronous nature of JS when the dfs() is called in the for loop at the bottom.

```js
var maxAreaOfIsland = function(grid) {
        let maxArea = 0
    let currArea = 0

    let dirs = [
        [0,1],
        [1,0],
        [-1,0],
        [0,-1]
    ]

    function dfs(r,c){
        if(grid[r][c] === 0) return
        
        currArea++
        grid[r][c] = 0
        for(let [row,col] of dirs){
            let nr = r+row
            let nc = c+col
            if(nr<0 || nc< 0|| nr >= grid.length|| nc >= grid[0].length){
                return
            }
            dfs(nr,nc)
        }
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j< grid[0].length; j++){
            if(grid[i][j] === 1){
                
                currArea = 0
                dfs(i,j)
                if(currArea > maxArea){
                    maxArea = currArea
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return maxArea
};

console.log(maxAreaOfIsland( [[1],[1]] ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if the `dfs` function is meant search around a non-zero location, incrementing `currArea` as it finds more non-zeros, and taking care not to run off the edge of the matrix. The `return` in that  boundary check, however, gives up the search when it should just `continue`.  One change, marked with a comment...

```js
var maxAreaOfIsland = function(grid) {
        let maxArea = 0
    let currArea = 0

    let dirs = [
        [0,1],
        [1,0],
        [-1,0],
        [0,-1]
    ]

    function dfs(r,c){
        if(grid[r][c] === 0) return
        
        currArea++
        grid[r][c] = 0
        for(let [row,col] of dirs){
            let nr = r+row
            let nc = c+col
            if(nr<0 || nc< 0|| nr >= grid.length|| nc >= grid[0].length){
                continue;  // <-- notice, we keep searching
            }
            dfs(nr,nc)
        }
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j< grid[0].length; j++){
            if(grid[i][j] === 1){
                
                currArea = 0
                dfs(i,j)
                if(currArea > maxArea){
                    maxArea = currArea
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return maxArea
};

console.log(maxAreaOfIsland( [[1],[1]] ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I guess you need to check if the cell is valid in grid before going forward.

```
var maxAreaOfIsland = function(grid) {
        let maxArea = 0
    let currArea = 0

    let dirs = [
        [0,1],
        [1,0],
        [-1,0],
        [0,-1]
    ]

    function dfs(r,c){
        if(r<0 || c< 0|| r >= grid.length|| c >= grid[0].length)
                return
        if(grid[r][c] === 0) return
        
        currArea++
        grid[r][c] = 0
        for(let [row,col] of dirs){
            let nr = r+row
            let nc = c+col
            dfs(nr,nc)
        }
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j< grid[0].length; j++){
            if(grid[i][j] === 1){
                
                currArea = 0
                dfs(i,j)
                if(currArea > maxArea){
                    maxArea = currArea
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return maxArea
};

console.log(maxAreaOfIsland( [[1],[1]] ))
```

I recomend using C++ as the same code will take 8 time less compared to JS

Comment: Hi thanks, im using JS and im preparing for a front end interview at a company notorious for doing, as for why I need to be able to solve this in JS im not so sure, but i hear doing leetcode is a must to get into these big tech companies